# How not to apply styles to all elements in an element with a special class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have css reset with next code

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 outline: none;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And I want these styles to apply to all elements except those that are in an element with a special class.

Like that

```
*:not(.without-reset) * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But it does not work. How to do it?

Comment: Try `*:not(.without-reset) {`

Comment: it's work for element with this class, but not for child elements

Comment: `not` will target more than you expect .. the second one is exactly the same as the first. Share your HTML structure

Comment: Try `*:not(.without-reset *) {`

Comment: Something like that <section class="without-reset"> content from server </section>

Comment: To get the children I think you have to do something like this: `*:not(.without-reset) *:not(.without-reset>*) {`  this will select all elements that have the class 'without-reset' and all the direct children of 'without-reset'.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a ton of headache. It'd be easier to just overwrite the styles on `.without-reset`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something in the line of this:

```
*:not(.without-reset),
*:not(.without-reset *){
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This prevents the styling on both the `.without-reset` elements, plus, it prevents all styling on their children (`.without-reset *`).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something in the line of this:

```
*:not(.without-reset),
*:not(.without-reset *){
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This prevents the styling on  the `.without-reset` elements, as well as preventing all styling on their children (`.without-reset *`).